# How to manage race condition in a service worker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I'm passing data using [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) from my main `app.tsx` to my service worker.

Here's the relevant code in `app.tsx` which sends the buildId to the service worker upon registration:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const buildId = 123;

    if (buildId && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register(`/sw.js`)
        .then((registration) => {
          if (registration.active) {
            registration.active.postMessage({
              type: 'BUILD_ID',
              value: buildId,
            });
          }
        })
    }
  }, []);
```

And here's how I'm receiving it in `service-worker.js`

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.1.2/workbox-sw.js');

let CACHE_NAME = 'cache-456';

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  self.skipWaiting();
});

// Accepting value of buildId via the postMessage and appending to cache name
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'BUILD_ID') {
    CACHE_NAME = 'cache-' + event.data.value;
  }
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/'),
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: CACHE_NAME, ***// This equals cache-456, but I want it to equal cache-123***
  })
);
```

I successfully receive the data within the `message` event listener, but don't know how to pass that data to the CACHE_NAME variable inside `registerRoute()`.

What I've tried:

- Putting `workbox.routing.registerRoute(...` inside of the `message` event listener, so that it gets CACHE_NAME after it's been redefined. I get an error saying that workbox.routing.registerRoute must be run at the global level (aka it can't be nested).
- Using a promise so that registerRoute doesn't run until the 'message' event listener resolves, but that didn't work either for the same reason.
- Storing the buildId as a query param in the filename (e.g. service-worker.js?v=123) and grabbing the value from there instead of using postMessage(), but I was getting an error when trying to register a sw with a query param.

Pretty sure the issue is that the `message` event listener runs *after* `registerRoute`, but I don't know how to better control the order in which things run in a service worker.

Any ideas? Much appreciated!